# Processing 2.0 - Open file dialog

Tags: dialog, draw, processing

my goal is to select a file from a "file open" dialog box, read it and draw objects
based on the content of the file.
I found a way to open that dialog box (see skeleton code below), however the PDE program starts
drawing BEFORE I can select the file. As the drawing depends on the 
content of the selected file, I get a null pointer error.

My question is how can I select the file before the draw method starts ?

If I define my file (Amas.in) explicitely in setup(), all is well, the
program shows my output based on the given file.

If I use selectInput(...), I only get the dialog box asking me for the file name 
AFTER draw() has started, resulting in the pointer error.

If I define my file explicitely and then call selectInput(...), the
program starts drawing objects according to the initial file, then asks me
which new file I want; however, after I select my new file, the program
ignores the content of that new file.

Both the default Amas.in and my other file are in the data folder.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
String myInputFile ;

void setup() {

    selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");

    String[] lines = loadStrings("Amas.in");        // works
    //String[] lines = loadStrings(myInputFile);      // doesn't work

}

void draw() {

    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 9, 9);
    println("Selected at this point " + myInputFile);

}

void fileSelected(File selection) {

    if (selection == null) {
        myInputFile = "Amas.in" ;
        println("Default file is opened : " + myInputFile);
    } else {
        myInputFile = selection.getAbsolutePath() ;
        println("User selected " + myInputFile);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just check if your file is loaded in setup or even at draw, also i believe you want the declaration of lines outside setup, som thing like:

[CODE EDITED]

```
String [] myInputFileContents ;
String myFilePath;

void setup() {
  selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
  while (myInputFileContents == null) {//wait
  }
}

void draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 9, 9);
  println("Selected at this point " + myFilePath);
}

void mousePressed() {
  selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
}

void fileSelected(File selection) {
    if (selection == null) {
    println("no selection so far...");
} else {

    myFilePath         = selection.getAbsolutePath();
    myInputFileContents = loadStrings(myFilePath) ;// this moves here...

    println("User selected " + myFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! The thing is, and that is the problem, that the program doesn't wait for the answer to the dialog to continue, so if myInputFile is null, I get an error. The best way to see what I mean is to create a data folder with 2 files (Amas3d.in and another one), whose content is irrelevant in this skeleton code and run it. The fact is that draw() starts before the result of the dialog box is known. Having a test in draw would be a waste of CPU. There must be a way to wait for the answer to the dialog box before draw() is run. All other languages I know do that.

Comment: Here, now I think I understand you, you need to think in two different things, filePath and fileContents. I edited the code above again, check it out;

Comment: I did try something similar. So I do get the dialog, I select my file, I get the message "user selected ..." with the selected file, but now the draw() part is not activated at all. I think the program is in the while loop forever. I am still puzzled. Thanks for spending the time to answer though !

Comment: Well, here the code above **does** get to draw() perfectly. But while always have this danger... This is why I think I would do this check in draw with an if...

Answer (score 1):

The solution by v.k. is a proper one, since it uses the predefined methods in Processing, and eases better in the life of the program since it is allowed to run, just not display anything. It is (almost) always better to trust the provided framework instead of a hack, yet I will provide one as an alternative answer. This is especially useful if you want to pop the dialog before even setup() runs.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
String myInputFile ;

final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); 
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this); 
void setup() {

  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); 
    myInputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
  } 
  else { 
    println("Cancelled.");
  }
}

void draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 9, 9);
  println("Selected at this point " + myInputFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, would this work in Processing ? I prefer to open the dialog in setup(). As I wrote above, draw() starts regardless of the outcome of the dialog box. Unless I explicitly define myInputFile (which works) before opening the dialog, I get an error. If I enter a new file name in the dialog, it is not taken into account since draw() is already running at that time.

Comment: It does work ! As opposed to "selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");", this swing dialog actually waits for my input before running draw(). That's what I wanted, thanks Petros !

Comment: You are welcome! You can always move the JFileChooser in setup() and it would work the same way! Also, don't forget to accept an answer!