# Processing2 selectInput() P3D clash

Tags: opengl, file-io, processing

I've been studying this thread

[Processing 2.0 - Open file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665007/processing-2-0-open-file-dialog)
   with regard to the use of selectinput().
I'm hoping to import point data to construct some 3d plots.
I can import the data and construct the plot ok but when trying to use
selectinput() to choose a file I run into trouble.
The difficulty I am having is that selectinput() appears to be incompatible with a P3D
window.

Using OS X10.10

for example This code works

```
void setup() {

   size(400, 400,P3D);  //3Dgraphics specified
   background(0);
   stroke(255);
   frameRate(20);
}

void draw() {
   noFill();
   ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 90, 90);
```

and this works

```
String [] myInputFileContents ;
String myFilePath;

void setup() {
   selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
   while (myInputFileContents == null) {//wait   
      // println("wait");    //If there is nothing inside the curly brackets
      //delay(3000);         //this doesn't work
      size(400, 400 );///   If P3D is added it won't work
      background(0);
      //smooth();
      stroke(255);
      frameRate(25);
   }
}

void draw() {
   box(mouseX, mouseY, 150);
   println("Selected at this point " + myFilePath);
}

void mousePressed() {
   selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
}

void fileSelected(File selection) {
   if (selection == null) {
      println("no selection so far...");
   } 
   else {
      myFilePath         = selection.getAbsolutePath();
      myInputFileContents = loadStrings(myFilePath) ;// this moves here...

      println("User selected " + myFilePath);
   }
}
```

but if

```
size(400, 400);
```

is changed to

```
size(400,400,P3D);
```

The frame displays but it won't draw.

Could someone point me to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is some kind of frame loading problem. This "hackish" approached worked for me under OS X 10.10 Yoesemite. It should also work under windows. Oh and whenever you use selectInput() please use mouseReleased so the function only gets called once :)

1. Setup() gets called twice for whatever reason, this is why we have the didPreSelect boolean.
2. You call mousePressed instead of mouseReleased
3. The loop already had the screen selection in it, this is why i changed the loop.
4. The delay also has problems, this is why i added the delay inside the while-loop.

Man that was quite the challenge, +1 for asking.

PS: I added an exit() if you press cancel the first time you open the application, which should be more convenient.

```
String [] myInputFileContents ;
String myFilePath;

boolean didPreSelect = false;
boolean secondPress = false;
void setup() {
  if (didPreSelect == false)
  {
    didPreSelect = true;
    selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
  }
  //frame = null;
  while (myInputFileContents == null || myInputFileContents.length < 2) {//wait   
    delay(1000);
  }
  //this doesn't work
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  background(0);
  //smooth();
  stroke(255);
  frameRate(25);
}
void draw() {
  box(mouseX, mouseY, 150);
  //println("Selected at this point " + myFilePath);
}

void mouseReleased() {
  if(secondPress == false) secondPress = true;
  selectInput("Select a file : ", "fileSelected");
}

void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (frameCount < 50)
  {
    if (selection == null) {
      println("no selection so far...");
      if(secondPress == false) exit();
    } else {

      myFilePath         = selection.getAbsolutePath();
      myInputFileContents = loadStrings(myFilePath) ;// this moves here..
      println("User selected " + myFilePath);
    }
  }
}
```